# HTML list margin

Tags: html, html-lists, margin

I'm trying to make a numbered list but I'm getting a margin on the top and the bottom between the list and some text (I'm using Firefox).
When I try get rid of it with CSS, I loose the numbers and the indentation. Is it possible to get rid of the margin without loosing the numbers and list indentation?

If you use the following html:

```
<html>
<body>
BIG GAP V
  <ol>
    <li>hello</li>
    <li>there</li>
  </ol>
BIG GAP ^
</body>
</html>
```

You'll see that you get the following:

```
BIG GAP V
  <ol>
    <li>hello</li>
    <li>there</li>
  </ol>
BIG GAP ^
```

Comment: How exactly did you tried to get rid of margins?

Comment: What did you try to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change just the top and bottom margin:

```
ol {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just realized I used padding in the CSS instead of margin. Silly me. :(

Comment: @hatter: The padding is just used for the indention.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, if you want the best control over the layout of your HTML, you should use a reset CSS such as [Eric Meyer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)'s or the one from [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/). This removes any default formatting applied by browsers (which is often different for each browser). You can then apply the formatting (margins, padding etc.) that *you* want.